# VAST (Vpaid) Clicks; second ClickTracking node

Tags: flash, vast

I'm currently encountering a problem with a vpaid creative on different video players.
I'm using a flash vpaid creative hosted on my server. It includes the clickthrough urls (given via clicktag-parameters to the flash).
 nodes are specified in the VAST XML and should enable counting of clicks for the AdServer. 
There's also one -node in the VAST XML, but according to the VPaid-Specs this might by ignored.

This seems to work fine when I test it on the Google IMA test page with chrome. However, I don't count clicks on some of the video players I'm running the ad on. This behaviour has started in June. 
I'm also counting the clicks from within the flash, and the numbers are higher than those we're counting from the VAST (-Node).

The thing is, we're inserting two -Nodes in the VAST. Is it possible that the second one is discounted by some video players?

Kind regards,
der_seri

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your assumption is correct. In my experience, a lot of players, including those who claim to be VPAID compliant, are actually not **fully** VPAID compliant and might not offer the full functionality they should do.
JW Player is one of the best in my opinion- have you tested on their player? If not, try it here: http://demo.jwplayer.com/ad-tester/
If that still does not work, post your VAST and I don't mind taking a look.

Comment: Hi Oli, we believe that the flash swf caused the problem. We were able to deal with it by inserting a clone-class into the swf - it now loads correctly.